# How can I improve sql paging query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, pagination, paging

I use following query for paging in my application (MVC4, SQL Server):

```
string sql = "SELECT Id, Name, Date, allCount FROM (" +
             "SELECT Id, Name, Date, COUNT(Id) OVER() as allCount, " +
             "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC, Id ) AS RowNum FROM Products) AS SOD " +
             "WHERE SOD.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1 AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber) ORDER BY Date DESC";
```

This works for me, but I want to know is it a normal approach to count ***allCount*** many times? I am afraid that to count ***allCount*** many times, will affect the speed for bulk data. But, In view I need ***count of all products*** to make pagination. Is it normal code if not, how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would perhaps inline your Between operation parameters in your .net. You can control the calculation to run only once. I personally don't trust SQL server to decide what is "deterministic" since I have been bitten a few times. Also why do you need to return allcount in EVERY row. If you are using ADO.Net rather than an ORM, then you can control your SQL as you want.

Do

```
SELECT Count(*); 

SELECT id, 
       name, 
       date 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               name, 
               date, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY date DESC, id ) AS RowNum 
        FROM   products) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.rownum BETWEEN @Start AND @End 
ORDER  BY date DESC
```

Although I suspect that you can just use a `HAVING` clause instead of your inner query with `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it might seem from the resulting data, that the COUNT(Id)-operation is performed once for every record in the dataset, the count is in fact only performed once. The query optimizer knows that the expression `COUNT(Id) OVER()` is independent of the current record, which allows it to only do the count once.

As such, I don't see anything wrong with your query, in terms of paging.

Comment: Still increase bandwidth.

Comment: That is most likely negible, as OP is probably not returning more than 100 records at a time, tops. 100 recods times 4 bytes (count returns a 4-byte integer) equals 400 bytes - which is almost nothing.